# How can I detect if Windows Installer is installed?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, version

I've figured out a way to tell which version of the .NET framework is installed by reading previous SO posts, but I've not found anything about the Windows Installer.

Is there a registry key or anything similar that I could verify that Windows Installer 3.01+ is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"If you want to check the version of the Windows Installer on your system, check the version of MSI.DLL in the Windows\System 32 folder"

http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/08/05/448386.aspx

Answer (score 11):

To find out which version of Windows Installer you have installed on your PC, do this:

1. Click on 'Start'
2. Then click 'Run'
3. In the box type " msiexec " then click OK.
4. Then another box will come up and at the top of the box the first line should read which which version of  Windows Installer you have installed on your PC.
5. It should look something like this " Windows ® Installer. V 4.5.6001.22159 "

Answer (score 0):

You can just include the redistributable version of Windows Installer and not have to worry about it.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=889482FC-5F56-4A38-B838-DE776FD4138C&displaylang=en

Comment: Well I'm using the WPkg project to do installation of a product and its prerequisites automatically, so I need to be able to tell the program when to install it or if its already present.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file version of %SYS32%\msi.dll.  On XP, it's in c:\windows\system32.